# How do I setup a node server so that I can push updates with git?

Tags: linux, git, node.js

If I'm hosting my own node.js server, how would I go about making it so that I can push updates to the code like I would on Heroku?

I want to be able to host my source code on the same server as my node app and then whenever I push updates, it will restart the node app with the updated code. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a git `post-receive` hook.

From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> The `post-receive` hook runs after the entire process is completed and
>   can be used to update other services or notify users.

Your script could be something like

- Stop your node app
- Copy new files over old ones
- Restart node app

Be aware that your script should not take a long time to run as

> This script can’t stop the push process, but the client doesn’t
>   disconnect until it has completed; so, be careful when you try to do
>   anything that may take a long time.